Testkube helm deploy - setting artefact retention on minio to X last?
Hi is there a way to set up retention on testkube to only save few recent one? I am creating test with playwright, and with option to record video, they pretty quickly eat up space on pvc.
I checked out helm documentation (https://github.com/kubeshop/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/testkube) for something which would help but found nothing.
I can see that they are stored in minio, but I am not familiar enough with it to set up confidently set up some sort of retention on pod, and tbh, it feels like not optimal way. Same case with setting up some sort of script to clear out pvc via Cron Job.
Did anyobody happend to resolve similar case?
